# I can't find the error in a piece of jquery syntax?

Tags: jquery, css

[This can be previewed on eirenilog.tumblr.com ]

For some reason my jquery is not working in the slightest. I'm attempting to have the css of these divs altered when clicking on some buttons at the top so that they move, and yet nothing moves. If I alter the values manually within the css, it goes into position properly so I know it's not a css error. I've copied it almost exactly from a previous piece of work and yet something is eluding me?

Could someone please look over it to see what could be preventing the animation? (You can see that I've attempted both .css() and .animate() )

the css looks like this:

```
#game{
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    width:100%;
}
#about{
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#team{
    width:100%
    left:200%;
    position:absolute;
}
#gallery{
    width:100%
    position:absolute;
    left:300%;
}
#shop{
    width:100%
    left:400%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

and the jquery is as such:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
$(".game").click(function(){

    $("#game").css("left","0%");
    $("#about").css("left","100%");
    $("#team").css("left","200%");
    $("#gallery").css("left","300%");
    $("#shop").css("left","400%");
});    
$(".about").click(function(){
    $("#game").animate({left:'-100%'});
    $("#about").animate({left:'0%'});
    $("#team").animate({left:'100%'});
    $("#gallery").animate({left:'200%'});
    $("#shop").animate({left:'300%'});
});
$(".team").click(function(){
    $("#game").css({"left","-200%");
    $("#about").css("left","-100%");
    $("#team").css("left","0%");
    $("#gallery").css("left","100%");
    $("#shop").css("left","200%");
});
$(".gallery").click(function(){

    $("#game").css("left","-300%");
    $("#about").css("left","200%");
    $("#team").css("left","-100%");
    $("#gallery").css("left","0%");
    $("#shop").css("left","100%");
});
$(".shop").click(function(){
    $("#game").animate({left:'-400%'});
    $("#about").animate({left:'-300%'});
    $("#team").animate({left:'-200%'});
    $("#gallery").animate({left:'-100%'});
    $("#shop").animate({left:'0%'});
});
});    
</script>
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't for "Why doesn't this code work?" questions.

Comment: Open your browsers console (press F12) and you will see all the errors your code has.
@AlBlue Stackoverflow is for "Why doesn't this code work?" question, as long as the question contains the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Check Your Syntax**

You have an opening `{` that looks like the result of copy-pasting between your [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) calls that use them and your [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) that do not.

See the first line of your `$('.team').click()` function :

```
// Line 118
$("#game").css({"left","-200%");
```

should be :

```
$("#game").css("left","-200%");
```

After making this change, your code at least appears to work similar to what I imagine you are going after [as seen in this example](http://jsbin.com/reziviz/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Oooh! Yes, that's what I've been going for. I couldn't find an example for the life of me, and that's very kind of you to include a demonstration! Much Obliged!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add position to your css, your script should be as following:

```
   $(".game").click(function(){
    $("#game").css({"left":"0%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#about").css({"left":"100%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#team").css({"left":"200%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#gallery").css({"left":"300%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#shop").css({"left":"400%","position":"absolute"});
});    
$(".about").click(function(){
    $("#game").animate({"left":"-100%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#about").animate({"left":"0%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#team").animate({"left":"100%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#gallery").animate({"left":"200%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#shop").animate({"left":"300%","position":"absolute"});
});
$(".team").click(function(){
    $("#game").css({"left":"-200%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#about").css({"left":"-100%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#team").css({"left":"0%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#gallery").css({"left":"100%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#shop").css({"left":"200%","position":"absolute"});
});
$(".gallery").click(function(){

    $("#game").css({"left":"-300%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#about").css({"left":"200%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#team").css({"left":"-100%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#gallery").css({"left":"0%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#shop").css({"left":"100%","position":"absolute"});
});
$(".shop").click(function(){
    $("#game").animate({"left":"-400%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#about").animate({"left":"-300%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#team").animate({"left":"-200%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#gallery").animate({"left":"-100%","position":"absolute"});
    $("#shop").animate({"left":"0%","position":"absolute"});
});
```